# Storing and displaying ₹ (rupee symbol) html (xslt) -> java -> Sql Server 2016

Tags: java, sql-server, tomcat, xslt, currency

I'm having difficulties getting an html page to pick up a rupee symbol (₹), store it into an SQL Server 2016 database and then retrieve it for display.

Important to note here is that I need to enter the actual symbol not the html version.

The basic flow of the page is that an administrator can add a new currency to the application via a web interface. There is a text box where
they would enter the actual rupee symbol ₹ and hit submit. This then passes the parameters via an HttpServletRequest to a java back end.
The java backend just inserts/updates this value to a SQL Server 2016 table in a field nchar(10).

When the page is refreshed it runs a select against this table and displays all the valid currencies.

The problem is that when the java application retrieves from the HttpServletRequest request object the symbol ₹ becomes â?¹. I can see this in the
debugger, I appreciate that this might be due to my debugger not being able to display this so I go forward.

The java (jdbc) updates the field. I view the field using Sql Server Management Studio and it displays â?¹ in both text and grid view.
I know that SSMS can dispay this symbol as I can insert it directly and it works. So it looks like the information is lost at the html>java request.

The web page itself is legacy and built using xslt. I have added some more details below of where I'm up to.

The website runs on tomcat 8 and the pages are built using xslt, the back end is java.

**In the front end I have a text field in an EditCurrency page**. I enter ₹ in the symbol field and hit submit.

The relevent fragments of the xslt page that is used to build the the front end are:

```
<!--header indicates page is utf8-->
```

```
            <xsl:param name="csrfToken"/>

            <xsl:param name="currencyFormatError"/>

            ...



            <!-- on submission the EditCurrency java class is called. method=POST indicates it should allow UTF8 request URL's as is my understanding-->



            <form id="cmanager" name="cmanager" onsubmit="return(vNewCurrency())" action="../servlet/webpay.website.admin.EditCurrency" method="POST">

                                                                                                                            <input name="csrfToken" type="hidden" value="{$csrfToken}"/>

                                                                                                                            <table width="100%" cellpadding="0" cellspacing="0" border="0">
```

The tomcat 8 server's server.xml set to encoding UTF-8. I understand this allows the request/response to handle UTF-8:

```
    <Connector port="8080" protocol="HTTP/1.1"

           connectionTimeout="20000"

           redirectPort="8443" URIEncoding="UTF-8" />
```

**Java class EditCurrency:**

```
//Retrieves symbol from the HttpServletRequest req

            //symbol returns â?¹

            String symbol = (String) getParameter(PARAM_SYMBOL);
```

I've also tried to set the HttpServletRequest req using the following but it does nothing:

```
try {

            req.setCharacterEncoding("UTF-8");
```

} catch (UnsupportedEncodingException ex) {

```
            java.util.logging.Logger.getLogger(EditCurrency.class.getName()).log(Level.SEVERE, null, ex);
```

}

**Sql Server:**

Value â?¹ appears in the nchar(10) field.

Display html:

â?¹ is displayed when the screen is refereshed with this updated value.

**So question is how do I fix this up!!??**

I had considered some sort of reference table of all currencies and their display values etc but it doesn't seem correct way of doing it.

Answer (score 0):

Unless every tool in the chain, *including whatever you use to look at the intermediate results*, is UTF-8 capable you will see garbage at some point.

The Unicode code point of the Rupee symbol is `0x20B9`, which is UTF-8 encoded as three bytes `0xE2 0x82 0xB9`.  If you attempt to display that in a tool that uses ISO-8859-1 you see

```
0xE2 = â   
0x82 = ? (there is no character in ISO-8859-1 for code 0x82, so you see a question mark)
0xB9 = ¹
```

So it appears the symbol is correct in the database, but you are displaying it incorrectly.

To "fix" this problem you must ensure that your tools are all set to UTF-8, and that the web server is configured to include the UTF-8 declaration in the HTML it sends.

Comment: If it displays as `â?¹` when viewing the field using Sql Server Management Studio, then it is *not* correct in the database.

Comment: It could be correct if Management Studio is configured to use ISO-8859-1.  It's also possible that the database is incorrectly configured, but the field still contains the correct 3-byte sequence for the Rupee symbol.  The OP hasn't given enough details to pinpoint which parts of the tool chain are misconfigured.

Comment: This would indicate otherwise: *"I know that SSMS can dispay this symbol as I can insert it directly and it works."*